# Replace letters in column to generate new column

Tags: r, linux, awk

I have a tab-delimited file which contains two columns(ref and alt). I want to make new column by replacing alt column letter in the ref column. But I don't want any replacement for empty rows and letters like TTGA( whose length is more than 1)

following is my input file

```
ref alt
T   C
C   
T   A,C
G   TTGA
C
```

Expected output

```
ref alt         
T   C   C   T   T
C       C   C   C
T   A,C T   A   C
G   TTGA    G   G   G
C       C   C   C
```

the explanation for the output

1)In ref column `T`is there in first column,second row, and in adjacent alt column there is `C` present in second column,second row, so i print ref column as new column as it is( see 3rd column) and then i  replaced `T` with `C`from alt column.

2. There is `C` in first column, third row and in adjacent alt column there is nothing so i will not paste ref column as it is as new column.
3. There is `T` in ref column at first column, 4th row and in adjacent alt column there is `A,C` (second column,4th row) so paste ref column as it is (4th column )and i replaced `T` with `A` first and then again I paste the ref column as it is and replaced `T` with `C`( 5th column, 4th row)
4. In first row ,5t column `G` is there and in adjacent alt column `TTGA`(length is more than 1) is there so i will not paste ref column as it is as new column.
5. `C` is there in first column, 6th row but in adjacent alt column there is nothing to replace, so I will not paste ref column as it is as new column.

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do to your file using pseudocode or flowchart?

Comment: @Daweo I have edited my question. Please let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Awk solution

File `./replaceletters.awk`:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = "\t"
}
# First line
NR == 1 {
    print $1,$2
    next
}
# Case: Only one column:
#  A -> A; empty; A; A; A
NF == 1 {
    print $1,"",$1,$1,$1
    next
}
# Case: Two columns, one letter on second column:
#  A; B -> A; B; B; A; A
NF == 2 && length($2) == 1 {
    print $1,$2,$2,$1,$1
    next
}
# Case: Two columns, two letters on second column:
#  A; B,C -> A; B,C; A; B; C
NF == 2 && $2 ~ /^.,.$/ {
    C1 = C2 = $2
    gsub(/,.*$/, "", C1)
    gsub(/^.*,/, "", C2)
    print $1,$2,$1,C1,C2
    next
}
# Case: Other cases with two columns
#  A; X -> A; X; A; A; A
NF == 2 {
    print $1,$2,$1,$1,$1
    next
}
```

Executable modes:

```bash
chmod +x ./replaceletters.awk
```

Launched like:

```bash
./replaceletters.awk input01.txt
```

Output:

```
ref alt
T   C   C   T   T
C       C   C   C
T   A,C T   A   C
G   TTGA    G   G   G
C       C   C   C
```

Comment: given awk code is perfectly fine for me but if the number of rows in my input file is more than 100 then what modification do I have to do to run this awk code.

Comment: @SunilPachakar This awk script works as is on any rows as you want